# Using itertools library to get combinations of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to generate combinations of an object of lists in Python and was looking into [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or similar functions to calculate combinations. Since `itertools`.product generates combinations from multiple arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Cities": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "New York"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "Boston"
        }
    ],
    "People": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "Michael"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "Ryan"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Value": "Jim"
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "Value": "Phyllis"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to generate a list that shows all combinations of people living in each city. So in the case above a list of 8 values.

My code below looks like:

```
import json
import itertools


def main():
    combinations = []
    with open('people.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    combinations = list(itertools.product(*data))
    print(combinations)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running I get a completely different result:

[image]

How can I modify my code to get the result I want?

**Note:** It doesn't have to use `itertools`, I just thought `itertools` is used for calculations like these

Comment: Is using ```itertools.product``` a requirement?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Not at all. I just thought it would be the solution with the least amount of code

Comment: `itertools.product` is the right tool for this job - I believe you are just giving it the wrong data. I'll build an answer

Comment: how so the expected result is "list of 8 values"? Do you mean the 8 possible combination of city and person - 2 x 4?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Python != Javascript. This is a `dict`, (well, it is an object as well, but *everything* is an object). Note, itertools.product doesn't expect "arrays" (supposing you mean `list`), rather, the functions in `itertools` accept *arbitrary iterables*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why you get the output that you do:

When you do `list(itertools.product(*data))`, the same thing is passed to `product` that you see when you do:

```
for x in data:
    print(x)
```

ie., you did

```
itertools.product(['Cities', 'People'])
```

which is why you got the product of the characters in those two strings (yay duck typing!)

```
[
 ('C', 'P'),
 ('C', 'e'),
 ('C', 'o'),
 ('C', 'p'),
 ('C', 'l'),
 ('C', 'e'),
 ('i', 'P'),
 ('i', 'e'),
 ('i', 'o'),
 ('i', 'p'),
 ('i', 'l'),
 ('i', 'e'),
 ...
]
```

---

### How to get the output you want:

You're using `product()` right, but giving it the wrong data.

```
cities = [c['Value'] for c in data['Cities']] # Extract all cities Value from list-of-dicts
people = [c['Value'] for c in data['People']] # Extract all people Value from list-of-dicts
print(list(itertools.product(cities, people))) # Product
```

This gives the output:

```
[
 ('New York', 'Michael'),
 ('New York', 'Ryan'),
 ('New York', 'Jim'),
 ('New York', 'Phyllis'),
 ('Boston', 'Michael'),
 ('Boston', 'Ryan'),
 ('Boston', 'Jim'),
 ('Boston', 'Phyllis')
]
```

---

If you want the *`dict` objects* instead of the `Value` keys, you can simply pass those objects to `product()`:

```
print(list(itertools.product(data['Cities'], data['People']))) # Product
```

which gives

```
[
  ({'Id': 1, 'Value': 'New York'}, {'Id': 1, 'Value': 'Michael'}),
  ({'Id': 1, 'Value': 'New York'}, {'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Ryan'}),
  ({'Id': 1, 'Value': 'New York'}, {'Id': 3, 'Value': 'Jim'}),
  ({'Id': 1, 'Value': 'New York'}, {'Id': 4, 'Value': 'Phyllis'}),
  ({'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Boston'}, {'Id': 1, 'Value': 'Michael'}),
  ({'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Boston'}, {'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Ryan'}),
  ({'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Boston'}, {'Id': 3, 'Value': 'Jim'}),
  ({'Id': 2, 'Value': 'Boston'}, {'Id': 4, 'Value': 'Phyllis'})
]
```

as expected.

Answer (score 2):

To perform the job you have described, using the data you have shown, this script will do it:

```py
import json
import itertools


def main():
    combinations = []
    with open('people.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    combinations = list(itertools.product(data['Cities'], data['People']))
    print(combinations)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The only difference is that I'm specifying which data to use from the data structure.

The output (I have formatted it for readability):

```
[
  ({"Id": 1, "Value": "New York"}, 
   {"Id": 1, "Value": "Michael"}), 
  ({"Id": 1, "Value": "New York"}, 
   {"Id": 2, "Value": "Ryan"}), 
  ({"Id": 1, "Value": "New York"}, 
   {"Id": 3, "Value": "Jim"}), 
  ({"Id": 1, "Value": "New York"}, 
   {"Id": 4, "Value": "Phyllis"}), 
  ({"Id": 2, "Value": "Boston"}, 
   {"Id": 1, "Value": "Michael"}), 
  ({"Id": 2, "Value": "Boston"}, 
   {"Id": 2, "Value": "Ryan"}), 
  ({"Id": 2, "Value": "Boston"}, 
   {"Id": 3, "Value": "Jim"}), 
  ({"Id": 2, "Value": "Boston"}, 
   {"Id": 4, "Value": "Phyllis"})
]
```

---

If you instead wanted to perform a `product` between whatever keys are in the data set, you would want to do `itertools.product(data.values())`, but the code I have shown is clearer.